# How to detect phone function

Tags: html, web-applications, browser-feature-detection

I am building an html5 web-app which will hopefully be mainly run from a mobile device. The app has a phone number which when clicked, calls the number displayed.

This works great if the user is using an iPhone or Android etc, but what if the user is using an iPod Touch or iPad with no phone capabilities? On the iPhone simulator in XCode, i get an error message saying that safari cannot open the page.

Is it possible to detect if the device has a phone, and if not, disable the link

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using something like phoneGap?

Comment: Can't you just do user detection for iPhone/Android to print out phone # otherwise don't if it is any other device?

Comment: I don't know much about phoneGap but don't you need to store the files locally on the device?  My files must be run from a server.  As for detecting the phones, how do I capture them all?  Are there only a few or many?